# Swagger not opening when running in Docker container

Tags: c#, .net, docker, swagger

In my project I have set up Swagger with Swashbuckle like so in my Startup.cs:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1");
            });
```

When I run my application from Visual Studio I can access `localhost:123456/swagger` and get the API documentation, like it should be. However when I run my application through Docker with `docker-compose up` and access `docker_machine_IP/swagger` it just reroutes me to my applications front page, no Swagger page or errors at all, just back to the same page as if I didn't write `/swagger` at the end at all. I have tried with several different URLs, `/swagger`, `/swagger-ui.html` etc, but no difference. Are there any specific configurations that must be written in the Dockerfile or elsewhere to be able to access the Swagger documentation when running in a Docker container?

Docker-compose file:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  node-frontend:
    container_name: node-frontend
    build: ./ClientApp/
    command: npm run start
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
  dotnet-backend:
    container_name: dotnet-backend
    build: .
   #expose:
    #  - "80"
    links:
      - mssql-db
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
  nginx-reverse-proxy:
    container_name: nginx-reverse-proxy
    build: ./nginx/
    #command: tail -F /dev/null
    command: nginx -g 'daemon off;'
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    #  - "443:443"
    expose:
      - "80"
      - "443"
    links:
      - node-frontend
      - dotnet-backend
  mssql-db:
    container_name: mssql-db
    #image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
    build: ./Database
    environment: 
      - SA_PASSWORD=password
      - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
    volumes:
     - ./Database/:/scripts/
    ports:
      - "1433:1433"
    expose:
      - "1433"
    command:
      - /bin/bash
      - -c 
      - |
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

# Copy everything else and build
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Debug -o out Project.csproj

# Build runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .

EXPOSE 80

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "ProjectApi.dll", "--environment=Development"]
```

Comment: Share your docker-compose file.

Comment: Added docker-compose file in original question.

Comment: Did you get to the bottom of this please?

Comment: Did you get that working? I'm stuck at the same point....

Comment: I have the same problem